# Woocommerce returns a javascript redirect on calling rest api

Tags: php, wordpress, rest, ssl, woocommerce

Other routes work fine but when I call a Woocommerce route I get this response

```
<html>

<body>
    <script>
       document.cookie="_test=9c0baff2487e653655b215e2af2e8108 ; expires=Thu, 31-Dec-37 23:55:55 GMT; path=/" ;
document.location.href="http://XXXXX.infinityfreeapp.com/ecommerce/wp-json/wc/v3/products/categories?i=1";
   </script>
   </body>
   </html>
```

The site Is uploaded on Infinityfree , I installed a free ssl certificate, but it's not trusted on all browsers , including my android app, so I used http instead, the same response appears with https in post man after disabling ssl verification.
I didn't edit any code in the site except the jwt key in wp-config.php

this response appears in GET requests only.

Comment: Have you tried contacting Woocommerce for help? This seems like either an issue with their API documentation and your expectations or an error on their part.

Comment: @JamesOltmans WooCommerce worked fine on 000webhost , it's most likely an infinityfree issue that is ruining the WooCommerce api